# "UseDNS no" is conflict with "Match User xxx"?

Tags: sshd

Last night I added `UseDNS no` to my `sshd_config`, after I restarted ssh via `sudo service ssh restart`, I found sshd not started and there is no process listened on port 22, but after I deleted `UseDNS no`, it will work as before.

I have compared with another server's `sshd_config`, only three lines are different (this server used sftp, so these lines are added):

```
Match User editor
ChrootDirectory /opt/ljmall-staging/var/editor-rootfs
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I have tried commet `ChrootDirectory` and `ForceCommand`, it doesn't work, it means `Match User` and `UseDNS no` is conflicted?

```
Server OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Openssh-server: 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7
```

Comment: Configuring an SSH server is not programming. This question is off topic for this site.

Comment: oh, which site should I go? serverfault is right? @AndrewMedico

Comment: I have figured it out, my `UseDNS no` added after `Match User` line !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not in conflict, but `Match` creates a new conditional block and `UseDNS` is not allowed in the conditional blocks.

Moving `UseDNS` above the `Match` block will solve your issue.